# Use a derived class automatically

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I work on TTY communication with different protocols. I started to implement some code in C++ with classes. A parent class contains some basic functions (write, read...) with some virtual functions. Each protocol is a child class with specific functions. Currently in my application, I'm using directly my child classes, but I want to change the protocol dynamically.

Is it possible in this case to use the parent class as an automatic selector for the child class to choose? And to still use the parent after this selection?

For example (simplified):

```
class Parent
{
    void Write();
    void Read();
    void AutomaticProtocolSelector();//depending on the response of the device
    virtual void function1();
    virtual void function2();
};

class protocol1 : public Parent
{
    void function1();
};

class protocol2 : public Parent
{
    void function2();
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Parent *p;
    p->AutomaticProtocolSelector();//let's say protocol1 is selected
    p->function1(); //execute the function1 in the child class
    ...
}
```

I already read some posts about derived classes and the use of `dynamic_cats` and `static_cast`, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'll use this if it's not possible in the way I think.

Comment: It seems to be a better approach to use the [_Template Method Pattern_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method/cpp/1) in this case.

Comment: Or the abstract factory pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Comment: Certainly an interesting question, but rather broad without more precisions or a real example...

Comment: Note that dynamic cats are mainly used to produce runtime rainbows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be in a kind of bootstrapping problem. You want to use a pointer to `Parent` to create an implementation of the `Parent` class. In your program, you are dereferencing a pointer that has not been initialized.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Parent *p;                      // !! Not initialized
    p->AutomaticProtocolSelector(); // The application should crash here
    p->function1();

    // ...
}
```

Preferably initialize your pointers as `nullptr`, that might make it more obvious that something fishy is going on.

---

To let the `Parent` class provide an implementation of itself, you need a static factory method.

```
class Parent
{
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<Parent> createParent();

    void Write();
    void Read();
    virtual void function1();
    virtual void function2();
};
```

This can then be used in your application as follows:

```
int main()
{
    auto p = Parent::createParent();
    p->function1();
    p->function2();

    // ...
}
```

However, this also means that in your implementation of `Parent`, you need to know about some or all possible child classes. This feels a bit backwards, you generally don't want your parent classes to know about their child classes.

As Alexandre Thouvenin also advised, it might be best to move the construction of a child class into a separate factory class.

```
class ParentFactory
{
public:
    ParentFactory() = default;

    std::unique_ptr<Parent> createParent() const;
};
```

In the implementation of the `createParent` method, you then create an instance of one of the child classes.

Then in your application code, create a factory and use it to get hold of an implementation of the `Parent` class.

```
int main()
{
    ParentFactory factory;

    auto p = factory.createParent();
    p->function1();
    p->function2();

    // ...
}
```

**Note:** I used some C++11 features, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was not aware of this type of classes, very interesting!

Comment: @PierreOlivier You may just have chosen the wrong words but do note that there is no notion of _different types of classes_ in C++. Classes are commonly composed according to one or more [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern). Implementing one or more of these patterns in your application will generally make it more scalable and maintainable. In this case, the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) seemed to fit your application well.